# android action menu item with equal width

Tags: android, menu

I want to create option menu both with equal size.  I have lost many days but couldnt solve it yet !!
Below is the layout file action_menu.xml i am using

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/add"
      android:title="@string/add" />
<item android:id="@+id/send"
      android:title="@string/send" /> 
</menu>
```

so in this case Add is taking a smaller space and Send is taking rest of the space !!
Please help

Here is the link for my view which is not yet fixed ! (I have given this image link as I have not acquired enough badge that allowed me to upload image in stackoverflow)
https://www.facebook.com/zoogaru/photos/pcb.324125821108138/324125687774818/

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: I dont have much rate that I can upload a screenshot .. I will try to put it some where

Comment: Just upload it to imgur or something

Comment: Here is the link for the view you can see Add and Send https://www.facebook.com/zoogaru/photos/pcb.324125821108138/324125687774818/ I want them to be equal size and couldnt find a solution yet.

Comment: That looks fine to me. They're displayed as expected. What's the problem?

Comment: Is there a solution that I can make them equal size ! There is difficulty while pressing Add vs Send. I personally didn't like this way but had released it as I could not fix it. Anyway Thanks for your response.

Comment: Why do you want them to be the same size?